# How do I store an array at a specific address?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I need to store an array at a specific address (0x10000200). How would I do this? 
would I do something like

> lui $v0,0x10000
>
> addi $v0,$v0,0x100

or does that only set $v0 to the address not create the array at the address..? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To store an array at a specific address use a data-segment starting at that address:

```
.data 0x10000200
    array: .space 400 #enough space for 100 integers
```